# ELIFECYCLE error when installing bcrypt on node. CXX Error?

Tags: node.js, compiler-construction

After installing OS X Mountain Lion and XCode, I'm getting this error:

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Air:fme jong$ npm install bcrypt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt/0.7.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt/0.7.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0

> bcrypt@0.7.0 install /Users/jong/Workspace/fme/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
make: c++: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:215:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:674:10)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jong/Workspace/fme/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/jong/Workspace/fme
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.45
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jong/Workspace/fme/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have a feeling that it doesn't know which compiler to use. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I just need to install the Command Line Tools from the downloads panel in XCode

Answer (score 0):

xCode doesn't bundle command-line tools by default. Apple explains it in their [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that your Node.Js is version 0.10 and some modules only work with the previous 0.8.22 version which you can get here: http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/06/node-v0-8-22-stable/